# How to smoothly move a button in cocos2d Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I have a jump button, that when clicked the player in game jumps. That button should be movable, how could I do that? I have seen the `CCSprite` moving images but don't know how to do that with a button and I don't have a `UIViewController` class, the scene is pushed by the `CCDirector`.

Also how could we zoom in and zoom out of scene a little bit to make it more featuring.

Comment: Do you want to move that as the game progresses?

Comment: No its a jump button on scene and i want it to be movable on any part of screen to make user comfortable and set the button according to his choice, any time whenever user wishes

Comment: Hi meet even i need a bit more help, how to share the facebook message with a dialog, if the button is on the cclayer class. Because i have done many application and integrated facebook as those xib files were uiviewcontroller so we could easily set delegate and navigate. And this is my first project so i would like to have that help from you if you have shared message on facebook from any of your developed game if possible

Comment: So you want to something like when you reached high-score , you want to share that on facebook like that?

Comment: No its a simple message which has a button in beginning of the game and end of play,no score is updated on facebook, because i am not able to set delegate of facebook class and the fbdialogdelegate along with fbsessiondelegate in cclayer class where the game scene is played

Comment: I am not getting what you are saying. If you can, then send me mail on meetsbrahmbhatt@gmail.com with your question or queries.

Comment: Probably extend CCMenu ... and use some kind of 'long touch' detection to control button movement and also firing the 'selected' and 'unselected' methods of the appropriate menu item. Use ccTouchMoved to move the button. If button moves, DONT fire 'selected'. If button does not move, fire 'selected' - schedule a short delayed method to do that. Dont fire 'unselected' if there was movement. sort of. not tested. I use a similar approach to detect long touches for the purpose of displaying 'help' info on any menu item.

Comment: please refrain from having peers upvote your question - I find it hard to imagine this kind of (very unclear) question receiving 8 upvotes in a day (especially on or near the weekend)

Comment: Do you want it to be draggable? So the same touch that might press the button, can drag it instead?

Comment: you could do it manually by implementing touchesBegan/Ended

Answer (score 0):

If the button is made by CCMenu, then you could use either actions or ccTouchesMoved method.

But if the button is made by UIButton, then you can use ccTouchesMoved and change the position of the UIButton based on where the user has dragged his finger across the screen.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to create a HUDLayer, so everything I'm writing from now on will have this in regard.

The HUDLayer would be a `CCLayer` that is on top of the others, and fixed on the screen. In order for it to be on top, it needs to be added last or with the proper zOrder.

In this layer, you have to map the event ccTouchesBegan, and just work with the user's touches. For instance, the character could jump when the user hits the right side of the screen. In order to do this, just see if `CGRectContainsPoint(rightSideOfScreen, touchLocation)`, and if yes, make the character jump, and show the buttonSprite exactly on the touchLocation.

In order to hide the sprite, use ccTouchesEnded, so when the player will release the jump button, you could also hide the sprite.